# Why does an ASP.NET web application initially use the OS culture instead of the Internet Explorer 8 language when launched from Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, .net, culture

I have an ASP.NET page that looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="culturetest4webapp._Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title>CultureTest</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" runat="server" />
                <div>
                    <button type="button" onclick="buttonClicked();">Test</button>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function buttonClicked() {
                        var cultureName = Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.name;
                        alert(cultureName);
                    }
                </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my Web.config file, I use the following globalization settings:

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto"/>
```

I use Visual Studio 2008 SP1, running on an English Windows 7 x64 with Internet Explorer 8 installed. My OS regional settings are Danish (da-DK).

My preferred language in Internet Explorer is set to "French (France)" = "fr-FR" - just to make sure it is different from my da-DK OS culture and the default en-US culture used in Microsoft Ajax.

The problem is that when I launch this application from within Visual Studio 2008, the page will initially use the da-DK (OS) culture rather than - as expected - fr-FR.

If I refresh (F5) the page (still using the same browser instance that was launched from Visual Studio), I get the correct fr-FR culture.

If, within the Solution Explorer window, I right-click my Default.aspx page, select "Browse With ..." and select Internet Explorer (8), I get the same results: Wrong the first time, but right after a refresh. But if I use the Browse With ... dialog and select Firefox og Chrome, the page is using the correct culture on first view.

If I paste the URL into a new instance of Internet Explorer 8 (not launched from within Visual Studio), the page also uses the correct culture on first view, without the need to refresh it.

If I switch my default browser to Firefox or Chrome, I also get the correct culture on first view when running the application.

I have tried all of the above with Visual Studio 2010, targeting .NET Framework 3.5 as well as 4.0 with the same results: Firefox and Chrome work. Internet Explorer 8 does not.

I have also tried a similar development configuration, but with Internet Explorer 9 instead of Internet Explorer 8 and it would appear that Internet Explorer 9 **does** work correctly (like Firefox and Chrome).

This problem appears to be isolated to the "auto" culture setting. If I set culture to a fixed value, e.g. "de-DE", it works correctly on first view when launched from Visual Studio using Internet Explorer 8.

Though this seems to be isolated to Internet Explorer 8 and only happens when launching the application from within Visual Studio (either from the Debug menu or the Browse With ... dialog) and that it is not something that would affect the end user, I would still like to know what the problem is and whether there is a workaround for it, as VS2008/VS2010 combined with Internet Explorer 8 (not 9) is what I am working with these days.

Comment: I had a similar problem years ago, unfortunately I cannot recall the workaround. Will try retrieve from memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing *client settings* with *server settings*.

Web.config specifies settings that are used by server-side code, not JavaScript (or VBScript) code running in the browser.

Comment: The EnableScriptGlobalization attribute causes a __cultureInfo variable to be injected into the page, which overrides the default en-US __cultureInfo of the Microsoft Ajax script to be overridden. After that, as shown in my example, properties such as Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.name are available from client-side JavaScript. The culture attribute in the Web.config file determines the value of the injected variable. As I have already stated, this works in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9, but not in IE8. I have also mentioned that it works with a specific culture but not with "auto".

Comment: You're right. I missed that part. And I didn't RTFM. My bad. Are you using WebDev or IIS when this occurs?